# 2 diamond moderators closed a post

Tags: support, closed-questions

How did [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/380698/does-mobile-phones-use-tcp-ip?rq=1) get closed by two diamond moderators? I  was under the impression that a single diamond moderator vote to close immediately closed the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In January 2012, [I didn't happen to be a moderator yet](https://superuser.com/election).

Since the ♦ is added to the user names wherever they're displayed, this also retroactively affects all "closed as" messages, leading to:

> closed as off topic by slhck♦, Mokubai, Journeyman Geek, Nifle, Sathya♦

Free unicorn for somebody who finds a question closed by five diamond moderators.

Comment: [This is the closest I can get](http://superuser.com/questions/220297/boot-camp-or-virtualization) to a free unicorn: closed by 4 diamonds, before any of them were moderators.

Comment: @nhinkle It's a trick. [There are no such questions on SU](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/93009/questions-with-most-active-moderator-close-votes). Nobody will get a free unicorn.

Comment: @DanielBeck Although mods are exempted from the giveaway, you'd still deserve an honorable mention for finding [this](http://superuser.com/questions/223662/track-page-size-of-web-app-for-performance), which looks the best, IMO.

Comment: @DanielBeck dang. I was wondering if there was a data query for that but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @slhck I'd argue that the one I found is better, because even though there's one non-mod close voter, none of the mods had diamonds at the time of the closing. IMO that makes it better.

Comment: SO unsurprisingly only has a maximum of 3, while SF has [one question](http://serverfault.com/questions/203240/colo-ing-in-seattle) with four moderators, impressive considering they only have 7 moderators total. Now they just need to [elect EEAA](http://serverfault.com/election/2) in the next election.